# Modificación del título en ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

¿Es posible modificar en el título de mi gráfico mostrando una parte de ella en itálica? Es decir, ***MI*** **TÍTULO** que muestre **MI** en itálica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma posible, es, gracias a que los textos en `ggplot` "entienden" de [expresiones matemáticas de dibujo](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html), hacer algo así:

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y = disp)) +
  labs(title=expression(paste("Esta es ", italic("una prueba"), " en italica")))
```

Sino, también puedes ser muy cómodo usar el paquete `ggtext` para customizar el código de ciertos textos, por ejemplo para tratarlos como `markdown`

```
library(ggtext)
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y = disp)) +
  ggtitle("Esta es _una prueba_ en italica") +
  theme(plot.title = element_markdown())
```

Comment: Excelente Patricio, muchas gracias