# Cómo poner parte del Texto en Negrita en un script R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Me gustaría que en el labs de un plot en el apartado (caption = "Data:leagues/NBA_2020  | Plot: Manolo") poner solo la palabra Data y Plot en negrita.
He intentado usando estos símbolos "
**" acotando la palabra, y nada
Alguna idea?
gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Modificación del título en ggplot2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/365696/modificaci%c3%b3n-del-t%c3%adtulo-en-ggplot2)

Comment: Deberías dar un ejemplo de tu código, ya que no esta claro que tipo de sistema gráfico estás usando, base?, lattice? ggplot? si fuera este último, arriba te dejé un enlace.

Comment: Si, perdona,  ggplot

Comment: Ya he leído tu enlace muchísimas gracias otra vez, solucionado con esto